# Как передать вложенную таблицу из пакета в процедуру? Ошибка: PLS-00488: должен быть типом

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

В спецификации пакета объявлена коллекция с фиксированный набором значений:

```
create or replace PACKAGE CATEGORYS_MONITORING IS
    
    TYPE t_rec is table of varchar2(200 byte);
    t_categorys t_rec:=t_rec('Beverages General','Beauty General');
    
    PROCEDURE GENERATE_ROWS(l_category_name varchar2);
end CATEGORYS_MONITORING;
```

Надо передать коллецию подпрограмме, которая после проверки запустит процедуру:

```
declare
    subtype trep is CATEGORYS_MONITORING.t_categorys;
    CA1 CATEGORYS_MONITORING.t_categorys;
    CA2 trep;
begin
    for iter in CA2.first .. CA2.last
    loop
        IF CA2(iter)='Beverages General' THEN 
            CATEGORYS_MONITORING.GENERATE_ROWS(CA2(iter));
        END IF;
    end loop;
end;
```

> Ошибка:PLS-00488:'CATEGORYS_MONITORING.T_CATEGORYS' должен быть типом.

Так как типы, между собой не совместимы, использовал `subtype` и к `t_categorys`, но всё равно ошибка.

Comment: Во второй строке, объявление subtype, нужно category_monitoring.t_rec использовать, в третей строке тоже, потом только := и коллекцию

Comment: Не путайте тип данных и его сущности ([на фиддле](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=512d3aa2c84656e34218b99c3dfa1eb5)).

Comment: @максимильин Опять ответ не помог? Уж постарался попроще объяснить.

Comment: 0xdb, ваш ответ помог от 31 мая 17:26 ;)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Что надо делать, если ошибка не совсем понятна? Надо создать пример, где ошибка воспроизводится, и упрощать его, пока причина ошибки не станет очевидной (или не исчезнет).

Упрощённо то, что в вопросе:

```
declare
    type t is table of varchar2(8);
    a t := t ('aaa','bbb');
    subtype subt is a;
begin null;
end;
/
ORA-06550: line 4, column 21:
PLS-00488: 'A' must be a type
```

- `а` - это то, что *содержит коллекция*, или сущность коллекции
- `t` - это то, что только определяет, что *может содержать коллекция*, или тип коллекции

То есть, когда поймёте разницу, получится:

```
declare
    type t is table of varchar2(8);
    a t := t ('aaa','bbb');
    subtype subt is t;
    b subt := a; 
begin null;
end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```